# Python2: List splitting syntax - tail of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sequence, slice

Why does `sequence[1:0]` return an empty list when `sequence[1:]` or `sequence[1:n] (where n >= sequence length)` returns the tail of the list successfully?

I'm pretty sure it's to do with the way that python iterates over the loop, but I can't fathom why it wouldn't work, considering it works for numbers less than zero.

Example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l[1:]
[2,3,4]
>>> l[1:100]
[2,3,4]
>>> l[1:0]
[]
>>> l[1:0:1]
[]
>>> l[1:-2]
[2]
```

Comment: Because `0` < `1`; there is nothing between those two indices unless you use a *negative* stride. `l[1:0:-1]` is not empty.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ``-1`` < ``1`` too. Does this have something to do with the negative indices being symbolic? Like python will interpret the index ``-1`` as ``len(sequence) - 1``?

Comment: Negative indices are always subtracted from the length, yes. See the duplicate question. Note that the third slice parameter is not an index, it's the stride.

Comment: Negative indices are a special case made possible by the fact that they can't be normal indices.

Comment: I know how to use slices, this is just an odd case I encountered. The problem seems to be that python will normalise negative indices and indices >= length but it does nothing if the stop index is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the elements backwards, you need to pass the step as a negative value

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
print l[1:0:-1]
# [2]
```

When you say `l[1:0]` Python takes [the step value as 1, by default, `step` is `1`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1be39dc4409a/Objects/sliceobject.c#l140).

And when [`step` is greater than 0 and `start` is greater than or equal to `stop`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1be39dc4409a/Objects/sliceobject.c#l177), the length of the slice to be returned will be set to 0. So, an empty list will be returned.

```
if ((*step < 0 && *stop >= *start) || (*step > 0 && *start >= *stop)) {
    *slicelength = 0;
}
```

When you use negative indices for [`start`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1be39dc4409a/Objects/sliceobject.c#l160) or [`stop`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1be39dc4409a/Objects/sliceobject.c#l171), Python adds length of the sequence to it.

Comment: I did not ask how to get the elements backwards, please re-read the question

Comment: The part of the linked document doesn't contain the immediate problem but it gives enough information to infer where the problem lies